# Attaching OnMouseOver event for all the URLs in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, onmouseover

I want to attach OnMouseOver even for all the anchor tags in a page. But i if any of the anchor tags already has a OnMouseOver even i dont want to replace it. I just want to add my event handler there.

How can i achieve it through Javascript or JQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior is to *add* not replace an event, so just use [`.mouseover()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('a').mouseover(function() {
    //do something
    alert('My url is: ' + this.href);
  });
});
```

[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/2A7JU/1/).  Or maybe you're after [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/), for example if you had the [color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) or [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) and you wanted to animate the color:

```
$(function() {
  $('a').hover(function() {
    $(this).animate({ color: '#123456' });
  }, function() {
    $(this).animate({ color: '#000099' });
  });
});
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/2A7JU/)